# Вызов процедур в Yii2. function does not exist

Tags: php, yii2, postgresql

Развернут Yii2-basic.
Подключена база Postgre

```
'class' => 'yii\db\Connection',
'dsn' => 'pgsql:host=192.168.2.100;port=5432dbname=db',
'username' => 'user',
'password' => '1111',
'charset' => 'utf8',
```

При вызове процедуры никаких ошибок нет. 
Однако, когда использую построитель запросов, ловлю ошибку.

```
SQLSTATE[42883]: Undefined function: 7 ERROR: function public.guser(integer, text, text, text, integer) does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT public."guser"('1'::integer, 'usr'::tex...
^
HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
The SQL being executed was: SELECT public."guser"('1'::integer, 'usr'::text, '300'::text, '192'::text, '0'::integer)
```

Вот вызываемый код:

```
$db = Yii::$app->db;
$cmd = $db->createCommand("SELECT public.\"guser\"('1'::integer, 'usr'::text, '300'::text, '192'::text, '0'::integer)")->queryAll();
```

Comment: Что за функция такая guser?  Скажите пожалуйста что должен делать ваш запрос?

Comment: Поместите сюда рабочий запрос, который можно выполнить непосредственно в консоли pgsql.

Comment: приведите код хранимки `guser`. `\sf guser` в psql. А ещё меня очень сильно настораживает отсутствие точки с запятой или пробела после номера порта в dsn. Парсер здесь ошибку к сожалению не даёт и dbname тихо игнорируется. То есть вполне вероятно, что вы работаете вообще не в той БД о которой думаете.

Comment: в строке dsn случайно не пропущено `;`? port=5432dbname=db

Answer (score 0):

Исключение говорит о том, что `postgres` не нашел функции в схеме public c именем `"guser"` и входными параметрами типов `(integer, text, text, text, integer)`.

Собственно это исключение постгреса, так что непосредственно к `Yii` это отношения не имеет.

**Внимательно проверьте:**

1. в какой схеме вы создали эту функцию;
2. какие типы принимаемых параметров объявлены.

**Например**, в постгрессе (да и в других бд) можно объявить 2 функции `guser`.
Одну как `integer, text, text, text, integer`, а вторую `integer, bigint, text, text, integer`

Comment: Если я вызываю этот запрос в каком-нибудь sql-менеджере, то проблем никаких нет

Comment: @Радик Камалов, приложите DDL для этой хранимки